Read Met Office Data Point JSON into Panda
I am using the MetOffice Datapoint API to download UK Weather data as a JSON. I would then like to read that JSON file into a pandas DataFrame. The format of the JSON file is as shown
{"SiteRep":{"Wx":{"Param":[{"name":"FDm","units":"C","$":"Feels Like Day Maximum Temperature"},{"name":"FNm","units":"C","$":"Feels Like Night Minimum Temperature"},{"name":"Dm","units":"C","$":"Day Maximum Temperature"},{"name":"Nm","units":"C","$":"Night Minimum Temperature"},{"name":"Gn","units":"mph","$":"Wind Gust Noon"},{"name":"Gm","units":"mph","$":"Wind Gust Midnight"},{"name":"Hn","units":"%","$":"Screen Relative Humidity Noon"},{"name":"Hm","units":"%","$":"Screen Relative Humidity Midnight"},{"name":"V","units":"","$":"Visibility"},{"name":"D","units":"compass","$":"Wind Direction"},{"name":"S","units":"mph","$":"Wind Speed"},{"name":"U","units":"","$":"Max UV Index"},{"name":"W","units":"","$":"Weather Type"},{"name":"PPd","units":"%","$":"Precipitation Probability Day"},{"name":"PPn","units":"%","$":"Precipitation Probability Night"}]},"DV":{"dataDate":"2024-07-20T09:00:00Z","type":"Forecast","Location":{"i":"3210","lat":"54.5181","lon":"-3.615","name":"ST. BEES HEAD","country":"ENGLAND","continent":"EUROPE","elevation":"124.0","Period":[{"type":"Day","value":"2024-07-20Z","Rep":[{"D":"SSE","Gn":"9","Hn":"93","PPd":"91","S":"7","V":"GO","Dm":"19","FDm":"18","W":"15","U":"3","$":"Day"},{"D":"NW","Gm":"22","Hm":"93","PPn":"80","S":"16","V":"VG","Nm":"11","FNm":"9","W":"12","$":"Night"}]},{"type":"Day","value":"2024-07-21Z","Rep":[{"D":"WSW","Gn":"16","Hn":"78","PPd":"50","S":"11","V":"VG","Dm":"16","FDm":"13","W":"7","U":"5","$":"Day"},{"D":"S","Gm":"29","Hm":"94","PPn":"85","S":"18","V":"MO","Nm":"13","FNm":"11","W":"15","$":"Night"}]},{"type":"Day","value":"2024-07-22Z","Rep":[{"D":"WSW","Gn":"29","Hn":"90","PPd":"55","S":"18","V":"VG","Dm":"17","FDm":"13","W":"12","U":"5","$":"Day"},{"D":"NW","Gm":"20","Hm":"89","PPn":"9","S":"13","V":"VG","Nm":"12","FNm":"11","W":"0","$":"Night"}]},{"type":"Day","value":"2024-07-23Z","Rep":[{"D":"WNW","Gn":"20","Hn":"69","PPd":"5","S":"11","V":"VG","Dm":"18","FDm":"15","W":"3","U":"7","$":"Day"},{"D":"WSW","Gm":"9","Hm":"91","PPn":"4","S":"7","V":"VG","Nm":"11","FNm":"12","W":"7","$":"Night"}]},{"type":"Day","value":"2024-07-24Z","Rep":[{"D":"SSW","Gn":"29","Hn":"74","PPd":"60","S":"16","V":"VG","Dm":"18","FDm":"14","W":"7","U":"6","$":"Day"},{"D":"SSW","Gm":"25","Hm":"95","PPn":"81","S":"16","V":"MO","Nm":"14","FNm":"12","W":"15","$":"Night"}]}]}}}}

I have fomatted this to make it easer to see here:
{"SiteRep":{
"Wx":
{"Param":[
{"name":"FDm","units":"C","$":"Feels Like Day Maximum Temperature"},
{"name":"FNm","units":"C","$":"Feels Like Night Minimum Temperature"},
{"name":"Dm","units":"C","$":"Day Maximum Temperature"},
{"name":"Nm","units":"C","$":"Night Minimum Temperature"},
{"name":"Gn","units":"mph","$":"Wind Gust Noon"},
{"name":"Gm","units":"mph","$":"Wind Gust Midnight"},
{"name":"Hn","units":"%","$":"Screen Relative Humidity Noon"},
{"name":"Hm","units":"%","$":"Screen Relative Humidity Midnight"},
{"name":"V","units":"","$":"Visibility"},
{"name":"D","units":"compass","$":"Wind Direction"},
{"name":"S","units":"mph","$":"Wind Speed"},
{"name":"U","units":"","$":"Max UV Index"},
{"name":"W","units":"","$":"Weather Type"},
{"name":"PPd","units":"%","$":"Precipitation Probability Day"},
{"name":"PPn","units":"%","$":"Precipitation Probability Night"}]},
"DV"
{"dataDate":"2024-07-20T09:00:00Z","type":"Forecast","Location":
{"i":"3210","lat":"54.5181","lon":"-3.615","name":"ST. BEES HEAD","country":"ENGLAND","continent":"EUROPE","elevation":"124.0","Period":[
{"type":"Day","value":"2024-07-20Z","Rep":[
{"D":"SSE","Gn":"9","Hn":"93","PPd":"91","S":"7","V":"GO","Dm":"19","FDm":"18","W":"15","U":"3","$":"Day"},
{"D":"NW","Gm":"22","Hm":"93","PPn":"80","S":"16","V":"VG","Nm":"11","FNm":"9","W":"12","$":"Night"}]},
{"type":"Day","value":"2024-07-21Z","Rep":[
{"D":"WSW","Gn":"16","Hn":"78","PPd":"50","S":"11","V":"VG","Dm":"16","FDm":"13","W":"7","U":"5","$":"Day"},
{"D":"S","Gm":"29","Hm":"94","PPn":"85","S":"18","V":"MO","Nm":"13","FNm":"11","W":"15","$":"Night"}]},
{"type":"Day","value":"2024-07-22Z","Rep":[
{"D":"WSW","Gn":"29","Hn":"90","PPd":"55","S":"18","V":"VG","Dm":"17","FDm":"13","W":"12","U":"5","$":"Day"},
{"D":"NW","Gm":"20","Hm":"89","PPn":"9","S":"13","V":"VG","Nm":"12","FNm":"11","W":"0","$":"Night"}]},
{"type":"Day","value":"2024-07-23Z","Rep":[
{"D":"WNW","Gn":"20","Hn":"69","PPd":"5","S":"11","V":"VG","Dm":"18","FDm":"15","W":"3","U":"7","$":"Day"},
{"D":"WSW","Gm":"9","Hm":"91","PPn":"4","S":"7","V":"VG","Nm":"11","FNm":"12","W":"7","$":"Night"}]},
{"type":"Day","value":"2024-07-24Z","Rep":[
{"D":"SSW","Gn":"29","Hn":"74","PPd":"60","S":"16","V":"VG","Dm":"18","FDm":"14","W":"7","U":"6","$":"Day"},
{"D":"SSW","Gm":"25","Hm":"95","PPn":"81","S":"16","V":"MO","Nm":"14","FNm":"12","W":"15","$":"Night"}]}]}}}}

When I read this is as a panda DataFrame, the frame only contains two rows, Wx and DF. How can I read this JSON into a pandas dataframe (so that "Wx" are the indexes and "DV" are the data values?). The following code does not do what I want it to...
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json(<data>)

The result is like this
Screenshot of DataFrame

"so that "Wx" are the indexes" doesn't really makes sense to me? You could get the data by something like pd.json_normalize(data, record_path=['SiteRep', 'DV', 'Location', 'Period', 'Rep'], meta=[['SiteRep', 'DV', 'Location', 'Period', 'type'],['SiteRep', 'DV', 'Location', 'Period', 'value']]) where data is the deserialised JSON (or replace it with json.loads(data) were data is a string ...).

Please show in your question the results you want; [mre]

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

If data contains the dictionary from the question you can try:
columns = {}
for c in data["SiteRep"]["Wx"]["Param"]:
    columns[c["name"]] = f'{c["$"]} [{c["units"]}]'

values = []
for row in data["SiteRep"]["DV"]["Location"]["Period"]:
    for rep in row["Rep"]:
        values.append(
            {
                "Value": row["value"],
                **{columns[k] if k != "$" else k: v for k, v in rep.items()},
            }
        )

df = pd.DataFrame(values)
print(df.set_index(["Value", "$"]).unstack(1))

Prints:
            Wind Direction [compass]       Wind Gust Noon [mph]       Screen Relative Humidity Noon [%]       Precipitation Probability Day [%]       Wind Speed [mph]       Visibility []       Day Maximum Temperature [C]       Feels Like Day Maximum Temperature [C]       Weather Type []       Max UV Index []       Wind Gust Midnight [mph]       Screen Relative Humidity Midnight [%]       Precipitation Probability Night [%]       Night Minimum Temperature [C]       Feels Like Night Minimum Temperature [C]      
$                                Day Night                  Day Night                               Day Night                               Day Night              Day Night           Day Night                         Day Night                                    Day Night             Day Night             Day Night                      Day Night                                   Day Night                                 Day Night                           Day Night                                      Day Night
Value                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
2024-07-20Z                      SSE    NW                    9   NaN                                93   NaN                                91   NaN                7    16            GO    VG                          19   NaN                                     18   NaN              15    12               3   NaN                      NaN    22                                   NaN    93                                 NaN    80                           NaN    11                                      NaN     9
2024-07-21Z                      WSW     S                   16   NaN                                78   NaN                                50   NaN               11    18            VG    MO                          16   NaN                                     13   NaN               7    15               5   NaN                      NaN    29                                   NaN    94                                 NaN    85                           NaN    13                                      NaN    11
2024-07-22Z                      WSW    NW                   29   NaN                                90   NaN                                55   NaN               18    13            VG    VG                          17   NaN                                     13   NaN              12     0               5   NaN                      NaN    20                                   NaN    89                                 NaN     9                           NaN    12                                      NaN    11
2024-07-23Z                      WNW   WSW                   20   NaN                                69   NaN                                 5   NaN               11     7            VG    VG                          18   NaN                                     15   NaN               3     7               7   NaN                      NaN     9                                   NaN    91                                 NaN     4                           NaN    11                                      NaN    12
2024-07-24Z                      SSW   SSW                   29   NaN                                74   NaN                                60   NaN               16    16            VG    MO                          18   NaN                                     14   NaN               7    15               6   NaN                      NaN    25                                   NaN    95                                 NaN    81                           NaN    14                                      NaN    12

